# Combining dataframe

Tags: pandas, plot, spyder

**Disclaimer**: I am new using Python.

I have a pandas DataFrame `ri` indexed by date and with a column representing the closing price of a stock, named `Close`.

I want to plot 2016 and 2017 closing prices using the following :

```
ri.loc['2016-01-01':'2016-12-31','Close'].plot()
ri.loc['2017-01-01':'2017-12-31','Close'].plot()
```

I am using Anaconda and writing my lines in Spyder.
When I do the above in a Jupyter notebook using `%matplotlib inline` works as intended, namely plotting on the same graph, in two colors for the two years, and axis goes from `2016-01-01 to 2017-12-31`.

However, on Spyder, it plots both Series on the same graph but using 2017 dates only.

Thanks for the help.

Nicolas